# Checking if a field is a collection at runtime

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, jpa, reflection, spring-data-jpa

Given a `path`, from jakarta.persistence.criteria.Path, and a String `key` representing a property of the entity T contained. I want to know, at runtime, whether a certain field `key` of the entity T is a collection.

For example, with path: `jakarta.persistence.criteria.Path<Author>` and key: `"books"`. I'd like to check that `Author.books` is a collection (typically a many-to-many or one-to-many relationship defined in the hibernate entity).

I obtain the path reference from the root in the toPredicate method of my custom implementation of [JPA Specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specifications.html). I've found that collection fields are represented internally as SqmPluralValuedSimplePath but I'm not sure I fully understand how this works and would prefer to avoid reaching the Hibernate internals.

```kotlin
 override fun toPredicate(
        root: Root<T>,
        query: CriteriaQuery<*>,
        builder: CriteriaBuilder
    ): Predicate? {
        val nestedKey = criteria.key.split(".")
        val nestedRoot = getNestedRoot(root, nestedKey)
        val criteriaKey = nestedKey[nestedKey.size - 1]
        val fieldClass = nestedRoot.get<Any>(criteriaKey).javaType.kotlin
        // is there a better way?
        val isCollectionField = nestedRoot.get<Any>(criteriaKey) is SqmPluralValuedSimplePath<*>
        
    }

private fun getNestedRoot(
        root: Root<T>,
        nestedKey: List<String>
    ): Path<*> {
        val prefix = ArrayList(nestedKey)
        prefix.removeAt(nestedKey.size - 1)
        var temp: Path<*> = root
        for (s in prefix) {
            temp = temp.get<T>(s)
        }

        return temp
    }
```

Is there a better way to do it, maybe by using reflection?